# Putting Inputs into JSTL session variables to later display on screen

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, jstl

I keep looking online for answers to put my inputs into sessions so I can output on a receipt page but all of them are different.  Is there a preferred way someone could should me?

I will post my servlet and form below

### Form

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
    <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Customer Management</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="customerServlet" method="post">
        <c:set var="customer" items="${sessionScope.customers}">


        First Name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="firstName"/><br>
        <c:out value="${customer.getFirstName() }"></c:out>
        Last Name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" <c:out value="customer.getLastName()"></c:out>/><br>

        Email:<br>
        <input type="text" name="email"/><br>
        Phone Number:<br>
        <input type="text" name="phone"/><br>
        Phone Type:<br>
        <select name="thePhones" id="selectPhones">
            <option selected value="choose">
                Select a Phone
            </option>
            <c:forEach items="${sessionScope.phones}" var="current"  >
                <option>${current.getPhoneName()}</option>              
            </c:forEach>        
        </select><br>
        Street Address:<br>
        <input type="text" name="streetAddress"/><br>
        Apartment Number:<br>
        <input type="text" name="apartmentNumber"/><br>
        City:<br>
        <input type="text" name="city"/><br>
        State:<br>
        <select name="states" id="states">
            <option selected value="Wisconsin">
                Select a State
            </option>
            <c:forEach items="${sessionScope.states}" var="current"  >
                <option>${current.getStates()}</option>             
            </c:forEach>        
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </c:set>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Servlet

```
package edu.witc.Assignment03.controller;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
//import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
//import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
//import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
//import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;




import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import edu.witc.Assignment03.model.Customer;
import edu.witc.Assignment03.model.Phone;
import edu.witc.Assignment03.model.States;


@WebServlet(description = "servlet to get act as controller between form and models", urlPatterns = { "/customerServlet","/addCustomer","/addPet", "/customerManagement" })
public class CustomerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CustomerServlet() {
        super();
    }


    private void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();


        Phone phone = new Phone();
        States state = new States();


        Collection<Phone> phones = phone.getPhoneCollection();
        Collection<States> states = state.getStateCollection();

            session.setAttribute("phones", phones);
            session.setAttribute("states", states);

        //}

    }







    private List<edu.witc.Assignment03.model.Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();



 private void addCustomer(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request)//redirect to index
           throws IOException, ServletException {
    String url = "/customerManagement.jsp";
    processRequest(request, response);
        request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request,response);
    }

 private void addPet(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request)//redirect to index
         throws IOException, ServletException {
    String url = "/pets.jsp";
    request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request,response);
  }




    private Customer getCustomer(int customerId) {
        for (Customer customer : customers) {
            if (customer.getCustomerId() == customerId) {
                return customer;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }



    private void makeCustomerReceipt(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String url = "/receipt.jsp";
        request.setAttribute("customers", customers);
        request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request,response);
    }



    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        if("addCustomer".equals(action)) { 
            addCustomer(response, request);
            }
        else if("addPet".equals(action)) { 
            addPet(response, request);
        }


    }


    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // update customer
        int customerId = 0;
        try {
            customerId = 
                    Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        }
        Customer customer = getCustomer(customerId);
        if (customer != null) {
            customer.setFirstName(request.getParameter("firstName"));
            customer.setLastName(request.getParameter("lastName"));
            customer.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
            customer.setPhone(request.getParameter("phone"));
            customer.setAddress(request.getParameter("address"));
            customer.setCity(request.getParameter("city"));
            customer.setZip(request.getParameter("zip"));
            makeCustomerReceipt(request, response);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It is common to take session scope things and put them on request scope within the servlet, rather than have the JSP be coupled to some things being on the session specifically.  (What if there is no session and you want to provide values obtained a different way?)  But otherwise this appears fine for a homework assignment.  What is the actual question?  There are dozens of ways it could be done, some of which I personally prefer, but that doesn't make for something to which we can give a useful answer :)

Comment: I basically want to know how I would go about doing it.  I have gone a long way with this but I am trying to make it into jstl which I did for the select boxes but the inputs are giving me trouble.

Comment: Looks like you've already got the JSP/JSTL part.  What you are missing is in your servlet. To pull the variable `customers` (the list variable) from the session, modify it, and save it back to the session.

Comment: So I did the jsp/JSTL part correctly?  I didnt feel like I did

Comment: Why do you want the list of customers in the session? Does each user logged in have a different list of customers? If not, it doesn't make sense to put it in the session. If the list is always the same, you don't want to be duplicating it in memory for each user.

Comment: I need a session to store the values of the user input so I can transfer to a receipt page.  My other question is more current.  I am struggling. Any chance you can help me get my code going?

Comment: Ultimately for a receipt you want a record that's really stored. So you should be submitting from JSP to servlet via form. Saving values to database in servlet.  Setting request attributes and forwarding to a JSP that prints those request attributes.